# display tag and c choose tag

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I use the following code. But it is always go to the otherwise condition. I checked the value , and those are correctly passed from java to the jsp. Any missing points?

```
<c:when test="${pCount > 0}">
    <display:column class="colPCount" property="pCount " title="${titlePCount}" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <display:column class="colPCount" title="${titlePCount}">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</display:column>
</c:otherwise>
```

For the pcount>0 items, still displaying as  '-' in the display tag. Even I reverse the checking condition like pCount<0 in the first condition checking, the display tag always show the otherwise condition. It always pointing to the otherwise condition for every value.

Edited: Full Code

```
    <display:table class="displayTable" id="itemList"
        name="${sessionScope.itemList}" requestURI="listItem.action"
        pagesize="15" defaultsort="2" defaultorder="ascending" sort="list">
        <display:column class="colItemName" property="name"
            title="${titleItemName}" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"/>
        ...
        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${pCount > 0}">
            <display:column class="colPCount" property="pCount " title="${titlePCount}" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <display:column class="colPCount" title="${titlePCount}">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</display:column>
        </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </display:table>
```

Comment: Show us where you are setting `pCount` for use in the comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way: `${itemList.pCount>0}`

Comment: when I use the id of the display tag like this <c:when test="${itemList.pCount > 0}"> , it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using the display tag library incorrectly.

It looks like what you are trying to do is to display `row.pCount` if the value is greater than zero, otherwise display `-`. But what you're actually doing is telling the library to display the entire column differently based on something (`pCount`, which probably does not exist in the scope you are referencing it... or you're going to have to show us some more code).

Try something like this:

```
<display:column class="colPCount" title="${titlePCount}" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${row.pCount > 0}">
            <c:out value="${row.pCount}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            &nbsp;-&nbsp;
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</display:column>
```

Comment: it is showing still the same result after I tried that. I just add <c:choose> start and end tag before <c:when> and after </c:otherwise> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the variable `pCount = null`. Try to check `${not empty pCount and pCount>0}`.

Comment: I tired that. Still the same :( just one thing: there wont be no null value for pCount.